# Partitioner for result set from oracle database in spring batch

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-batch

I need to extract the results from query in to flat file. Is there a way to partition the result set so that it can be accessed by multiple threads.

I tried partitioning based on `ROWNUM` without sort, but when same query is executed by multiple threads `ROWNUM` does not remain same(because I am not sorting due to performance impact) and creates duplicates in output.

Comment: Rownum should be the same until your query executed multiple times fine the code where execute sql query and place a counter how many times it's executed on each step.

Answer (score 1):

Use [ORA_HASH](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions135.htm#SQLRF06313) to split rows into deterministic buckets:

```
select *
from
(
    select level, ora_hash(level, 2) bucket
    from dual
    connect by level <= 10
)
where bucket = 2;


LEVEL   BUCKET
-----   ------
    1        2
    3        2
    6        2
   10        2
```

It's a 0-based number.  Use `bucket = 0` and `bucket = 1` to get the other 2 sets.

Answer (score 0):

Use ROWID instead. ROWID is immutable for every record. Or just use the Primary key (or any other field with enough distinct values for that mather) to devide the data in subsets.

```
select * 
from table    
where SUBSTR(ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID),-1) IN ('A','a','0');

select * 
from table       
where SUBSTR(ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID),-1) IN ('B','b','1');

or 

select * 
from table       
where SUBSTR(ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID),-1) between 'A' and 'Z';
etc.
```

You'll have to experiment a little with the where clause. As far as I know the last character of rownum can contain [A-Z][a-z][0-9] + and /